How do I map multiple URLs to the same Controller using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping in a single Controller?
Here is my  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping config.
I am trying to map multiple URLs from the same Controller.  Not sure how to reference 2 different methods in the same Controller.
package com.empirestateids.configuration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping;

import com.empirestateids.controller.MainController;

@Configuration
public class SimpleUrlHandlerMappingConfig {

     @Bean
        public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
            SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping
              = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
            
            Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
            urlMap.put("/home", home());
            urlMap.put("/adminhome", adminhome());
            simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);
            
            return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
        }

        @Bean
        public MainController home() {
            return new MainController();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public MainController adminhome() {
            return new MainController();
        }
        
}

And here is my Controller
package com.empirestateids.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.empirestateids.domain.MainContent;
import com.empirestateids.service.LookupService;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@EnableWebMvc
@Component
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainController.class);

    private LookupService lookupService;

    
    /**
     * Home page
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView home(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        MainContent mainContent = new MainContent();

        String username;

        model.addAttribute("userName", "Username");
        mav.setViewName("home");
        return (mav);
    }
    
    public Map<String, String> getLookupMap(String lookupName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
        Map<String, String> lookupMap = null;

        lookupMap = (Map<String, String>) servletContext.getAttribute(lookupName);
        if (lookupMap == null) {
            lookupMap = lookupService.getLookup(lookupName);
            servletContext.setAttribute(lookupName, lookupMap);
        }

        return lookupMap;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/adminhome")
    public ModelAndView adminhome(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        mav.setViewName("adminhome");
        return mav;
    }
}

When I try to add both mappings with the same Controller I get the following error:
When I just have the single mapping, I can display the /home page.
What is the secret to reference the other endpoint?
both home.jsp and adminhome.jsp are in the following location:
/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp
/WEB-INF/pages/adminhome.jsp
15-Sep-2024 07:23:38.445 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'adminhome' method  com.empirestateids.controller.MainController#home(Model, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) to { [/home]}: There is already 'home' bean method com.empirestateids.controller.MainController#home(Model, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) mapped.


You don't, also your use of SimpleUrlHandlerMapping is wrong. Just remove it. Remove @Component from MainController as well as @EnableWebMvc.  Empty your config and add the @EnableWebMvc to it. The problem you have comes from the fact that you have 2 bean definitions for 1 URL and even worse there is another created for the annotation. Basically you are making things overly complex.

The problem is SimpleUrlHandlerMapping configuration creates two beans (home and adminhome) but both return the same MainController instance.
options:

use different controller instances
remove the SimpleUrlHandlerMappingConfig class and use @Controller with @RequestMapping to map URLs in MainController class.
(if you want to keep SimpleUrlHandlerMapping while pointing to the same controller class) remove @RequestMapping, and manually route requests inside MainController like implement org.spring framework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller

For simplicity, you might want to consider 2.

That worked using 2 Controllers..........thx
